# Would Non-Open Handset Alliance Android phones have Google Now?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google, google-now

I understand that whilst Android is free and open source, in order to use Google services, an OEM has to be approved to join the Open Handset Alliance (OHA).

One of the biggest additions to Android for Jelly Bean was Google Now. Just wondering, if I buy a non-OHA phone, does that mean it won't come with Google Now? If so, what will be in its place? Will it just be the old Google search app?

The other thing is, can non-OHA phones run Google services that are embedded into apps? For instance, if an app uses Google Maps, would it still run on my non-OHA phone?

Comment: Don't you think this is a rather speculative question? Who shall say for sure what manufacturer A does, or how manufacturer B accomplishes this, or what manufacturer C might come up with as replacement app for the one or the other? Moreover, it's quite broad, and includes a bunch of question (instead of one).

Comment: @Izzy - well the main things i want to find out is whether non-OHA phones are allowed to run google now and apps that have embedded google services.

Comment: Then maybe you re-phrase your question to reflect that, before it might be closed for being "too broad" or "speculative". In short: They might not be allowed to have the GApps *pre-installed*, but (root given) you can do that yourself anytime.

Comment: Google Now is part of the newer Google Search app. If you can install that app, then you should have Google Now.

Comment: @Izzy - so google doesn't block their apps from being installed on non-OHA phones? They just block it from being pre-installed?

Comment: To my understanding, that's about it (though they don't "block" from pre-install, but manufacturers would run into legal trouble if they pre-installed them without consent).

Comment: I saw a Xiaomi device, Redmi 1 with Play Store & Play Services preinstalled (I was watching when it's booted for the first time), despite that Xiaomi is not a member of OHA. It's using [MIUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI), which is based on CM. Whether this can be a proof to contradict your premise or not, I'm not sure.